# Refactor to filtering lists using LINQ

Tags: linq, list, find

I use several lists of similar objects. Anyone object has a List property. Basically, I need compare several lists.

I would have thought that LINQ would be an ideal way of doing this but after trying joins, extension methods, using yields, etc. I'm still having trouble.

any suggestions for refactor my code to using LINQ ?

Update: I'm refactor ContieneServidor (ContainsServer translate) method

```
 private static bool ContieneServidorRefactoring(List<GrupoServidorDto> datosGruposServidores, string nombreMaquina)
    {
            var total = datosGruposServidores
                 .SelectMany(g => g.Servidores)
                 .Where(x => x.Nombre.Equals(nombreMaquina)).Count();
            if (total > 0) return true;
            return false;
    }
```

My code:

```
var datosGruposServidores = new List<GrupoServidorDto>();    
var gruposCompletos = new List<GrupoServidorSeleccionado>();
var maquinasSeleccionadas = new List<string>();
...

// Comprobación de Máquinas
var maquinasNoEncontradas = new List<string>();
foreach (var g in gruposCompletos)
{
    foreach (var server in g.Servidores)
    {
        var encontrado = 
            ContieneServidor(datosGruposServidores, server.Nombre);
        if (!encontrado) maquinasNoEncontradas.Add(server.Nombre);
    }
}

foreach (var m in maquinasSeleccionadas)
{
    var encontrado = ContieneServidor(datosGruposServidores, m);
    if (!encontrado) maquinasNoEncontradas.Add(m);
}

if (maquinasNoEncontradas.Count > 0)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var sep = "";
    foreach (var maq in maquinasNoEncontradas)
    {
        sb.Append(sep + maq);
        sep = ", ";
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Máquinas no encontradas: " + sb.ToString());
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Máquinas no encontradas: " + sb.ToString());
}

}

private static bool ContieneServidor(
    List<GrupoServidorDto> datosGruposServidores, string nombreMaquina)
{
    foreach (var g in datosGruposServidores)
    {
        var servidor = g.Servidores.Where(s => s.Nombre.Equals(nombreMaquina));
        if (servidor != null && servidor.Count() > 0) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static bool ContieneServidorRefactoring(List<GrupoServidorDto> datosGruposServidores, string nombreMaquina)
{
        var total = datosGruposServidores
             .SelectMany(g => g.Servidores)
             .Where(x => x.Nombre.Equals(nombreMaquina)).Count();
        if (total > 0) return true;
        return false;
}
```

The types:

```
public class GrupoServidorDto
{
    public int IdGrupo { get; set; }

    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    private List<ServidorDto> servidores = new List<ServidorDto>();

    public List<ServidorDto> Servidores
    {
        get { return servidores; }
        set { servidores = value; }
    }
}


public class ServidorDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    public string IP { get; set; }

    public string Entorno { get; set; }

    public string Habilitado { get; set; }

    public string Tipo { get; set; }

    public int IdGrupo { get; set; }
}


[Serializable()]
public class GrupoServidorSeleccionado
{
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public int IdGrupo { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    private List<ServidorSeleccionado> servidores = 
        new List<ServidorSeleccionado>();

    [XmlElement()]
    public List<ServidorSeleccionado> Servidores
    {
        get { return servidores; }
        set { servidores = value; }
    }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public bool EstanTodasLasMaquinasSeleccionadas { get; set; }

    public GrupoServidorSeleccionado() { }
}


[Serializable()]
public class ServidorSeleccionado
{
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string IP { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Entorno { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()] // [XmlIgnore()]
    public string Habilitado { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Tipo { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public int IdGrupo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        string.Join(", ", gruposCompletos
                              .SelectMany(x => x.Servidores)
                              .Select(x => x.Nombre)
                              .Concat(maquinasSeleccionadas)
                              .Where(x => !ContieneServidor(datosGruposServidores, x))
                              .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you want:

```
var maquinasNoEncontradas = gruposCompletos
                   .SelectMany(g => g.Servidores)
                   .Select(x => x.Nombre)
                   .Concat(maquinasSeleccionadas)
                   .Where(x => !ContieneServidor(datosGruposServidores, x))
                   .ToList();
```

And then:

```
if (maquinasNoEncontradas.Count > 0)
{
    // This assumes .NET 4; it's *slightly* more awkward in .NET 3.5, but
    // still simpler than doing it by hand.
    string text = string.Join(", ", maquinasNoEncontradas);

    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Máquinas no encontradas: " + text);
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Máquinas no encontradas: " + text);
}
```

You *could* potentially build the comma-separated version and then test whether *that's* an empty string... but I'm not sure I would, to be honest.

Comment: you overlooked that `maquinasSeleccionadas` is a `List<string>`.  I'm scared to downvote you, but I'm sure you'll fix it

Comment: @smartcaveman: Fixed, thanks. (I find it a *lot* harder to read code when the variable names aren't meaningful *to me*. Not a complaint, of course - I'm sure they're more useful to the OP than English ones would be!)